# How to work out the highest value out of three outputs

Tags: pine-script

Morning,

I am trying to workout how to filter out the highest Initial Balance(IB) out of three IBs.

I am using the below to get the highest Price Action across a specific time frame, repeated three times for different market openings

```
var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
```

I thought either of the below would have worked but with no success

```
DailyIBHighest = ((highe_01> highe_02 and highe_03) = highe_01) or ((highe_02> highe_03 and highe_01) = highe_02) or ((highe_03> highe_01 and highe_02) = highe_03)


DailyIBHighest = highest(highe_01, highe_02, highe_03)
```

Thank you for your time.

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DailyIBHighest = max(highe_01, highe_02, highe_03)
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke That is clear from OP's question. No need to repeat.

Comment: Thank you Bjorn Mistiaen